# Help resolving an apparent contradiction with triangle internal angles

Tags: triangles, conic-sections, angle

I've been scratching my head over this for the last few days...

I've been doing some maths relating to orbital mechanics and elliptical orbits, and there's one simple thing that I can't get right. I can't figure out how to calculate the angle $\alpha$ between the edge of the ellipse and the two foci.

Let me illustrate with the case of an isosceles triangle:

[image: isosceles triangle inset into an ellipse, with a vertex at each of the foci. The angles made by the two foci and the edge vertex are both theta. The angle at the edge is alpha.]

First of all, it is immediately obvious that $\alpha = 180-2\theta$.
However if I calculate it in a different and more general way, I get a different result.

The length between the foci, $A$ is known and is equal to $2ae$ where $a$ is the semi-major axis and $e$ is the eccentricity, and the angle $\theta$ can be arbitrarily set. In this case it is chosen so that it forms an isosceles triangle for the sake of this question. $B$ is unknown but will be calculated, and $\alpha$ is unknown.

The cosine rule:
$$ C^2 = A^2 + B^2 -2ABcos(\theta)$$
side $B = C $ so substitute $C$ for $B$
$$B^2 = 4a^2e^2 + B^2 - 4aeBcos(\theta)$$
$$0 = 4a^2e^2-4aeBcos(\theta)$$
$$Bcos(\theta) = ae$$
$$B = \frac{ae}{cos(\theta)} $$
The sine rule can then be used to find $\alpha$:
$$ \frac{sin(\alpha)}{A} = \frac{sin(\theta)}{B} $$
$$ \frac{sin(\alpha)}{2ae} = \frac{cos(\theta)sin(\theta)}{ae} $$
$$ sin(\alpha) = 2sin(\theta)cos(\theta) = sin(2\theta)$$
$$ \alpha = sin^{-1}(sin(2\theta)) $$
$$ \alpha = 2\theta $$

Now, for almost all values of $\theta$, $\alpha$ quite clearly cannot both be equal to $2\theta$ and $180-2\theta$. But for the life of me I cannot figure out where my mistake is.

Comment: $\sin(180^\circ - \phi)= \sin( \phi)$ for all $\phi$ but you would not say this implies $180^\circ - \phi=\phi$

Comment: You chose $\theta$ specifically so that the triangle is isosceles, right? You are correct that for most values of $\theta$, $\alpha$ cannot be equal to both $2\alpha$ and $180-2\alpha$, but in this case you have chosen a $\theta$ such that it is. Your error, in other words, was in mistaking the special case for the general one.

Comment: You could have spared some computation observing that $B+B=2a$, that is $B=a$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca This is a toy version of my more general problem where B != C, for which that observation doesn't apply.